# What is BTU/hr gauge of Cisco ISR4461/K9?

Tags: cisco, routing, router

I searched everywhere but couldn't find it. If anyone knows the system, can answer?
How much BTU (British thermal unit) /hr uses by this router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first approximation, you can multiply the power consumption in watts by 3.4 to get BTU/hr.